# Viewport setting ignored in Phonegap Android app, but only on certain phones?

Tags: android, cordova, viewport, cordova-3

A user reported that the Viewport meta tag is being ignored on his phone, but it works everywhere I've tested.  Why would viewport work on one Android device and fail on another with the same OS version?

This is on a Phonegap 3.5 Android app that lays out everything to a set size (1800x1200) and then scales it to the device's size using viewport, like so:

```
var scale = windowHeight/appHeight;
var vport = "width=device-width, user-scalable=0, initial-scale="+scale+", 
    minimum-scale="+scale+", maximum-scale="+scale;
document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", vport);
```

This works fine everywhere I've tried it.  Works in the latest Firefox and Chrome, works when compiled to Android and run on a Nexus 5 or a Nexus 10 or Galaxy 3, and also when run on the emulator for SDK 19, 20 or 21.  The only place I've seen it fail is on SDK 17 (Android 4.2.2) or lower, but that should not be an issue, as I have android-minSdkVersion set to 19 (Android 4.4.2).

My problem is that a user reported that the Viewport setting is being ignored (the text is huge) on his Sony Xperia Z.  So my question is, how is it possible for Viewport support to vary on phones with the same OS?  For example, is it possible for two 4.4.2 phones to have different webkits?

Edit - is it possible that android-minSdkVersion is being ignored?  I haven't been able to confirm the user's SDK version, but when I try to install the production apk to a 4.2.2 emulator, it lets me.  I expected an "unsupported sdk" error or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was that the user was using 4.2.2 (where viewport is known to be dodgy) due to phonegap setting a lower minSdkVersion than I had specified in config.xml.  I'm trying to figure out why that might be [here][1].

Anyway, if you are here because of viewport issues, the useful things that came out of my research and my discussion in the comments with Jason M. Batchelor are:

- Make sure meta is really being updated (see Jason's answer)
- Make sure the minsdk is 19+, viewport behavior seems problematic on older OSes
- After much testing, the viewport setting that has worked best for me is:

  var scale = windowHeight/appHeight;
  var vport = "width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale="+scale+", 
  minimum-scale="+scale+", maximum-scale="+scale+", target-densitydpi=device-dpi";
  document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", vport);

However YMMV, it appears to depend on some of the CSS you use, whether you have any divs wider than the viewport, and possibly other things, so I would recommend testing on every sdk you support.

Comment: I never figured out whymy minsdkversion was being ignored, I ended up restarting with cordova instead of phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Did you confirm if the user is using the phone's built-in browser, or Chrome or Firefox Mobile? It's very possible that the webkit can be tweaked from phone to phone. For example, my Droid Turbo comes with Chrome as its default browser, but my Samsung Galaxy S3 had a system-browser that was webkit-based, which I replaced with Chrome.

More likely, the issue you are experiencing is that the meta tag does not support an ID. You didn't include specific source, but standard meta tag markup is this:

`<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">`

If your code looks like:

`<meta name="viewport" content="...etc...">`

Then trying to access it with document.getElementById() is going to give you sporadic results, if it works at all.

What you're going to have to do is search for the meta tag in some other fashion, like:

```
var vp = document.querySelector('[name="viewport"]');
```

Then you can work with vp as an object, along the lines that you're already expecting.

For more information on querySelector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Comment: This is an android app, not a webpage.  It uses the webkit that comes bundled with the OS, the user's browser should (I believe) not matter.

Comment: And yes, of course I can access the viewport with getElementById, otherwise it wouldn't work on all the devices I tested with.

Comment: You asked if there is a difference between devices, and my point was that the webkit implementation does vary from device to device. I would say that you got lucky on a small subset of devices, and that querySelector (which is supported on all Android devices back to 2.1) would be a safer approach. Nothing else you've tried has helped, so what's the problem with trying this?

Comment: Sorry to be terse; of course you're right that getElementById() should only be used on elements with a matching ID, the reason it works for me is that I set <meta id="viewport" name="viewport">.  I did try changing it to queryselector, same result.

Comment: In any event, I found someone with Android 4.1 and he was able to install my app from the Play store, in contravention to my android-minSdkVersion.  So I will probably delete this question and change it to either "Why is Viewport being ignored on Android 4.2.2" or "Why is the store ignoring minSdkVersion", but I've got some research to do first...

Comment: Fair enough. 
It could be some responsive CSS. Are you using any CSS frameworks in this, with breakpoints for different viewport sizes?

Comment: Nope, just hard coding appwidth/height to 1800x1200, and then setting font and div sizes explicitly by pixel sizes, and then scaling everything with viewport.  I'm really hoping to avoid reworking all of the CSS to be responsive (which was the whole point of viewport in the first place), and it seems to work everywhere I've tried except for Android 4.2.2.  F'rinstance, 4.1.2 looks fine.  Still digging, no gold yet...

Comment: Alright. Good luck. Cordova is ... a squirrely beastie.

Comment: Oh, hey! Did you see this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724567/how-to-deal-with-width-inconsistency-between-android-4-0-4-3-and-4-4-on-cordova?rq=1

Comment: I did, target-densitydpi=device-dpi doesn't seem to affect me either way.  I am curious to see whether 4.4.2 and 4.2.2 report different values for window.devicePixelRatio though, maybe I could query that and do something with it...

Comment: Progress!  On 4.2.2 it appears to scale right iff target-densitydpi=device-dpi AND user-scalable=yes.  I had tested both of those, but evidently not at the same time.  Now to go see if that works on other OSes...  and I'm still curious why it's letting people install it on older OSes anyway.  I have android-minsdkversion=19, and it throws the correct error on sdk=8 but happily installs on sdk=17.

Comment: I seem to recall something about minsdkversion being kind of a "guideline" for the compiler, but I would say that's a worthwhile question for a different thread here. Glad you've made some useful progress! You should update your question with an answer and mark that as the final solution so others can see a solution was found. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will, just want to make sure it really is working on all the emulators first.  I'm downloading some more old ones just to see which version it starts throwing INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK on.